# Panel with auto scroll redraw

Tags: c#, panel, draw

I have form that programmatically add a panel in it;

For each task coming in to my program, I add a label and 
progress bar to panel which have 30 pixel Y added to previous Y position.

But when panel get scrolls sometimes when want to scroll down,
positions multiplied and not in their exact position.

Remember, I checked and written Y positions to console and saw that Y position is ok, but panel does not show it correctly

I think problem is for panel draw method,
but don't know how to fix it.

Problem is that task 26 should come just after 25 but not in correct position, despite of console I've seen position is correct.

code to add controls:

```
 private static void AddTaskControls(int taskId)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "lbl" + taskId.ToString();
            lbl.Text = "Task " + taskId.ToString() + ":";
            lbl.Width = 57;
            lbl.Height = 13;
            lbl.Location = new Point(0, 25 + (taskId) * 30);

            ProgressBar pr = new ProgressBar();
            pr = new ProgressBar();
            pr.Name = "pr" + taskId.ToString();
            pr.Width = 180;
            pr.Height = 23;
            pr.Location = new Point(50, 20 + (taskId) * 30);

            Label lbl2 = new Label();
            lbl2.Name = "lbl" + taskId.ToString() + "List";
            lbl2.Text = "Starting " + taskId.ToString() + "";
            lbl2.Width = 200;
            lbl2.Height = 13;
            lbl2.Location = new Point(230, 25 + (taskId) * 30);
            //Console.WriteLine(lbl2.Location.Y + "taskid:"+taskId);


            if (panel1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                AddTaskControllsCallback t = new AddTaskControllsCallback(AddTaskControls);
                panel1.BeginInvoke(t, new object[] { taskId });
            }
            else
            {
                panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
                panel1.Controls.Add(pr);
                panel1.Controls.Add(lbl2);               

                pr.BringToFront();                
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MickyD I edited my question and added codes

Comment: @MickyD No, I don't have any special drawing. just controls that you see in in picture above.

Comment: So, how should I solve the problem?

Comment: I cant do that, because using InvokeRequired is needed, for updating label and progressbar values from multiple threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with threading. When  adding controls the **current scroll position** is used to **re-calculate** the **effective** `Location`. Weird? Yes..

So the reason probably is that your `Panel` **scrolls down** while you are adding new controls. I don't see where it happens but here is a tiny test to demonstrate the problem:

[image]

Looks familiar, right?

I enforce the scrolling in the code but in your case the reason should be similar, as should be the fix..

```
private void button20_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // lets add a few buttons..
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Top = i * 25;
        btn.Parent = panel2;
    }
    // ..now let's enforce a scoll amount of 111 pixels:
    panel2.AutoScrollPosition =  new Point(panel2.AutoScrollPosition.X, 
                                            -panel2.AutoScrollPosition.Y + 111);

    // ..and add a few more buttons..
    for (int i = 20; i < 40; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Top = i * 25;    // not good enough!
        // btn.Top = i * 25 + panel2.AutoScrollPosition.Y; // this will fix the problem!
        btn.Parent = panel2;
    }
}
```

So your code needs to set the `Locations` like this:

```
lbl.Location = new Point(0, 25 + (taskId) * 30 + panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
..
pr.Location = new Point(50, 20 + (taskId) * 30 + panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y));
..
lbl2.Location = new Point(230, 25 + (taskId) * 30 + panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y));
```

(Or you find out how the scrolling happens and prevent it.)

Comment: so I have to calculate 111px for example for each button when I want to redraw? and if value!=25px do this job? I should redraw every control in scroll event of panel?

Comment: No !!! Just use the 3 lines at the bottom of the answer, i.e. add the `AutoScrollPosition.Y` to the yvalues of all your three controls when adding them. Once they are placed no further action is needed.  The 111 was just an example of how scrolling messes up the locations and the problem only comes when (somehow) __scrolling during__ the process of __adding__ the controls..

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it is a lot easier to add a second panel inside the scrollable panel, add the controls to that second panel, and increase the size of the second panel. Any problems with scrolling position do not apply then.

So create a form, add a button, add a panel `panel1` with `AutoScroll = true;`, and add another panel `panel2` inside the first panel (with location 0, 0).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // lets add a few buttons..
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Top = i * 25;
        panel2.Controls.Add(btn); // Add to panel2 instead of panel1
    }

    // Recalculate size of the panel in the scrollable panel
    panel2.Height = panel2.Controls.Cast<Control>().Max(x => x.Top + x.Size.Height);
    panel2.Width = panel2.Controls.Cast<Control>().Max(x => x.Left + x.Size.Width);
}
```

Comment: Not sure how that would even work but imo it is not any easier than setting the locations right in the first place..

Comment: @Taw This way you don't have to take any scrolling position into account. If you are not sure how it would work, then maybe you can give it a try, and see for yourself.

Comment: ah, sorry i didn't quite get your idea. so, yes I guess it would work. but adding an extra panel when it really isn't needed seems still not 'much easier'. Note that my solution consists of nothing but __one added value__ to the y-positions.