# Control position changes when vertical scroll bar is displayed

Tags: c#, winforms

as soon as the vertical scrollbar of the panel is displayed the position of the control changes. the property `AutoScroll` in `Panel` is enabled
Code:

```
int an = 10;
private void Incoming_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MsgItem item = new MsgItem ("testing");
    item.Top = an;
    an = item.Top + item.Height + 10;
    panel2.Controls.Add(item);
}
```

the position of the control `MsgItem` is too far away when the scrollbar shows here is an example how it looks
[see the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFWSM.gif)

Comment: You may want to try working with "item.Location.Y" insteand of "item.Top"

Comment: You need to use the autoscrollposition, not just  item.Top when calculating: `an = item.Top + item.Height + 10 + panel2.AutoScrollPosition.Y;` - Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093489/panel-with-auto-scroll-redraw/38094702#38094702). I think this is a duplicate!

Comment: that not works how you say it https://i.imgur.com/0s3hOrL.gif

Comment: It will if you do it right, but there may well be more than one way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
var count = panel2.Controls.Count;
MsgItem item = new MsgItem("testing");
item.Top = count == 0 ? 10 : (panel2.Controls[count - 1].Bottom + 10);
panel2.Controls.Add(item);
```

For your original code, which is

```
int an = 10;
private void Incoming_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MsgItem item = new MsgItem("testing");
    item.Top = an;
    an = item.Top + item.Height + 10;
    panel2.Controls.Add(item);
}
```

the solution would be to track scrolling of your panel

```
private void panel2_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.ScrollOrientation)
    {
        case ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll:
            var change = e.NewValue - e.OldValue;
            an -= change;
            break;
    }
}
```

*So, for layout scenarios using `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` is recommended*

Comment: hey that works perfect, could you explain what the problem was?

Comment: When you scroll your panel the layout of child controls is changing and the value `an` is becoming wrong. See the update in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use FlowLayoutPanel with instead of Panel
and you don't have to set the Position

Comment: no incoming should be on the left side and outgoing on the right side